# How can I make all frames in my video become i-frames?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

Now I use ffmpeg to encode my video in c++. I need to decode a h264 frame without other frames. So I need to make all my frames in my video become i-frames. But I don't know how to set parameters in order to do this. What should I do if I need to make all my video frame i-frames?

Answer (score 2):

```
ffmpeg -i yourfile -c:v libx264 -x264opts keyint=1 out.mp4
```

-x264opts keyint=1 sets the keyframe interval to 1 (I believe you can also use -g 1). You probably want to set other rate control parameters also, e.g. -crf 10 (for quality) and -preset veryslow (for speed), see [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) page.